# jQuery selector what's difference between jQuery("element") and $("element")?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I used jQuery many times ago, but always used like this: `$(document)`. Lately i seen many times somebody using `jQuery(document)`, I don't know difference between them, I thought they are same.

But I have very hard problem now. You know most of jQuery plugin uses `$(document)` method. Now I have one **must use** plugin that uses `jQuery(document)`. I must include that, but after included I can't no longer use `$(document)` method and plugins which uses it.

How can I solve it?

Comment: They **are** the same. Maybe that plugin calls `jQuery.noConflict()` for no reason. Have a look at it's source.

Comment: I found `jQuery.noConflict();` from that library. Deleted that line :), and problem **solved** :), Can you write it as "answer" for later usage those who had problems like this? So I can give "answered", and they can see this working solution.

Comment: What is the plugin doing? Maybe it needs it...

Comment: I checked, plugin working well as before. It was 1 js file combined Jquery with http://sizzlejs.com/.

Comment: it would be nice if you posted some code.

Comment: @Gerelt: MMh. Ok then... but jQuery already includes sizzle... I'm confused now. But as long as it works for you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is just a short *reference* to the global `jQuery` object.

```
window.$ === window.jQuery // true
```

Most plugin authors make sure that the dollar sign really is referencing the jQuery object, by putting it into a self-invoking method.

```
(function( $ ) {
    // $(document)
}( jQuery ));
```

By invoking that anonymous method with the `jQuery` object as argument, we can access it within the method via `$`.

Answer (score 0):

[@jAndy provides a good explanation about `$` and `jQuery` in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608002/jquery-selecter-whats-difference-between-jqueryelement-and-element/6608034#6608034).

However for your specific problem, it seems that the plugin somehow makes `$` unavailable, which either means that it overwrites `$` with something else (unlikely) or that it calls [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

If it does, have a look *why* it is doing this. Maybe it includes another library that needs `$` for its own working.

Usually, plugins should never assume that `$` is available for them. @jAndy showed how to use `$` if only `jQuery` is available.

In addition if you put all your own code in the [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler, the first argument passed is the global `jQuery` object, so you can name the parameter as you want:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // your code here
});
```